# How to transform a regular reactive form in a multipart form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, ionic-framework

Im trying to upload a chunk of data (string, number, file, bool) to an api. Now the docs says its not a json but multipart schema. Since the api didn't accept the image with the normal form, I would need the multipart form to upload my data, right? Now I have a problem with transforming my normal form to a multipart form. I looked it up on the internet but found nowhere this approach. I already tried to do it somehow but it completely failed:( Also there is a difficulty where I need to call my file from the local storage(all these things worked in my normal form. I also wouldn't know how to exactly change my html to fit the new multipart form.

html(with set up of a normal form => can I keep that?):

```
  <form [formGroup]="categoryForm">

<ion-item>
         <ion-icon name="images"></ion-icon>
                <ion-checkbox formControlName="lock"></ion-checkbox>
 </ion-item>


    <ion-item>
      <ion-input [disabled]="tagList?.length > 0" formControlName="category"  name="tagValue"></ion-input>
      <ion-button (click)="addVal()" [disabled]="!categoryForm.valid || tagList?.length > 0">

    </ion-button>
    </ion-item>
</form> 
<ion-button (click)="apiSubmit()">POST</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

TS(first my working normal form then my failed multipart:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.storage.get('image_data').then((imageFile) => {
      console.log(imageFile)
      this.categoryForm.patchValue({
        image: this.storage.get('image_data')
      });

      this.storage.get('when').then((Data) => {
        this.categoryForm.patchValue({
          when: this.storage.get('when')
        });
      });

    });

    this.categoryForm = new FormGroup({

      'lock': new FormControl(true),

      'category': new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.maxLength(25),
        Validators.minLength(1),
        Validators.required
      ])),
      image: new FormControl(null),
      when: new FormControl(null),
    });


    const payload = new FormData();
    this.storage.get('image_data').then((imageFile) => {
      console.log(imageFile);
      this.payload.patchValue({
        image: this.storage.get('image_data')
      });
      payload.append('image': image) // stored retrieved file
      payload.append('category': category) // input string
      payload.append('lock': lock) // bool
      payload.append('when': when) // stored retrieved number (same principle as image)
}
```